# Jssor slider doesn't work when using IE

Tags: jquery, jssor

I'm currently working on a website and I used jssor slider on the front page. It works perfectly fine in Chrome & Firefox, but when viewed in IE the images are not displayed. The html elements are there (based on cursor which changes to ) but it's not shown. And when I view the error log in the console I see this (IE 9 up):

[image: Script error on IE version 9 up]

I've tried using compatibility view. The images shows up but still it's not working, and on the error log (IE 8 down):

[image: Script error on IE version 8 down]

Does this problem have to do with the script itself? My html codes where just copied from the demo on jssor's full-width slider. And when I tried it with IE it didn't work also, does anybody know on how to make this work on IE?

Comment: I have just tested again, there is no problem at my side. Please post full code of your page here, I will check it out ASAP.

Comment: I downloaded the plugin again, and copied the codes in the full-width demo of the plugin and it seems to be working now. I don't know what could have gone wrong. I just did what I did the first time...

Comment: Hi Jssor, the slider doesn't work in IE8 until the first click is made. the loading sign stays and the image doesn't auto slide until I click somewhere on the slider. It works fine in IE9+ and chrome and firefox. Please suggest.

Comment: I have the same issue @aayushdriger, did you find a resolution?

Comment: I decided to go with basic jQuery slider. If you check the JS code of the jssor files (jssor.utils.js line 473 to be precise), you'll find a section where it is clearly written in the comments that "**//IE 8- and chrome 1 won't fade well**". I tried to customize but no luck. Sorry for breaking the hard news.

Answer (score 2):

I had this very issue only to find out that the developer release a fix 3 days ago. Downloaded and replace jssor.js and jssor.slider.js and and ensure your outer slider container has a pixel dimension eg. 900px (not percentage). Hope this helps.